# Ajax in Rails for saving values and changing state

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i'm building an inventory system in Rails, where a user has an inventory and a warehouse and can move objects from one to the other. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like :

[image: Warehouse/Inventory]

Now, i know the basics of how ajax works in Rails, like creating js.erb files and rendering in js format. However, i'm not quite comfortable with using ajax to save values back to my models.

So, i suppose that every slot should have an id like 'inventory_slot_1' and 'warehouse_slot_1'. In my current inventory, you can drag and drop the objects without problem. But now, i want to save the state. I want to know if an item is moved from 'inventory_slot_1' to 'warehouse_slot_2' for example.

How would i go about doing that ? Any useful resources that would help me ?

Comment: I fear it's sheer jQuery, using `ajax` method. Be sure to check the value you get in the params though.